# PostgreSQL : Why "Time" type allocates the same size as "Timestamp"?

Tags: postgresql

Reading about Postgresql data types and specifically about ["Date/Time"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) types i noticed something weird (For me at least).

The **"Time"** data type allocates the same storage size (***8 bytes***) as the **"Timestamp"** type. Although **"Time"** is responsible of storing only the time while **"Timestamp"**  is storing both Date **and** Time being a super-set of time.

In addition both types have the exact same precision *(1 microsecond / 14 digits)* leaving me questioning why they both allocate 8 bytes unlike the "Date" Type which allocates 4?

[image: Date Time types]

Is it something internally which affects performance or what?

Comment: What's really strange is that `time with time zone` is larger than `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: @nwellnhof: I believe the difference is that "timestamp with time zone" is really badly named - it just means "I'll convert to UTC for you automatically" whereas "time with time zone" genuinely stores the UTC offset along with the time-of-day. Admittedly a UTC offset isn't the same as a time zone, but...

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, the documentation says: "For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's timezone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 86,400,000,000 microseconds in a day. That's more than 2<sup>32</sup>, so the result can't be stored in 32 bits. The next best option is 64 bits, i.e. 8 bytes.

Compare that with the `date` type which covers 4713BC to 5874897AD, i.e. 5879611 years. That's around 2147483820 days, which is less than 2<sup>32</sup> and so can be stored in a 32-bit integer. (In fact it's less than 2<sup>31</sup>, which may make various things slightly simpler.)

Comment: Yea that explains it. Although it would be helpful to provide a less precise format to reduce size because mostly in 98% of all use cases a precision of a second is more than enough.